# Rcaller 2.0 generated plot is rendering and empty output and the file (png) generated is also empty?

Tags: java, r, rcaller

The Rcaller 2.0 generated plot is rendering an empty output and the file (png) generated is also empty? posting the link for the code i have used

http://stdioe.blogspot.in/2011/07/rcaller-20-calling-r-from-java.html

I used the code in the link specified above and the application runs fine but the output is a blank console without any graph plotted. It also creates a png file which is empty. am i missing something or are there any steps to be followed to eliminate the problem i am facing.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please shorten your title and expand your question. Linking to an external site for your question does not make the question and its answers self contained on StackOverflow.

Comment: The Rcaller 2.0 generated plot is rendering an empty output and the file (png) generated is also empty? the link for the code i have used is http://stdioe.blogspot.in/2011/07/rcaller-20-calling-r-from-java.html

Comment: Reiterating your question does not change my comment...

Comment: Hii i got the output. 

**solution:**
The work around i did was to install rjava in my R environment. It solved the problem. 
i think the rjava is required to be installed in your R environment even though you import the rcaller jar file. 

I perceived it as the R caller would just call the R environment but your R environment must have the rjava to do the rest of the work.

If i am wrong please correct and a better explanation is welcomed...

Comment: i am new to stack overflow and i am new to certain standards you follow here so please bear with me for a few days so that i get used to things the way most of the users do here....

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Next time try and make the question self contained, even if that copying code from the website you llinked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hii i got the output.

**solution:** The work around i did was to install rjava in my R environment. It solved the problem.

I think the rjava is required to be installed in your R environment even though you import the rcaller jar file.

I perceived it as the R caller would just call the R environment but your R environment must have the rjava to do the rest of the work.

If i am wrong please correct and a better explanation is welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

rJava and RCaller are separate projects and you don't need to have rJava installed in order to use RCaller.

Only the R Package Runiversal is required and used by RCaller. Type

```
install.packages("Runiversal")
```

in R REPL and press enter before running RCaller. This is what you need.

If the generated R Code is invalid, RCaller will not handle the output or generated plots. You can also have a look at the generated code and output files in your os' temp directory.

Comment: Hey i tried the same initially but the code didn't give me the proper output.

Comment: thanks for the reply but can you be more explanatory. i understand that rcaller just converts the java code into r code and receives the output generated by R and handles the output. 

i din't get what is the REPL got to do with this??? can you please explain that...